# How to ignore users in VS 11 Sql Server Database project publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012

**Problem**
I can't figure out how to ignore users in my vs 11 beta sql server db project when publishing.

**Why is this a problem**
This is a problem because I want to keep the setting where I want to drop objects that are not in my project but *are* in the db being published to.  If I delete a sproc in my project I'd like to drop the sproc in my db.

Any ideas?  I've looked at all of the publish settings and just can't seem to figure it out....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encountered this as well, since it persists in Visual Studio 2012 RTM / SP1 with SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).  I reached out to Barclay Hill at Microsoft who works on the product, who confirmed that this is currently not possible:

> It is frequently asked for i.e drop everything, but users, permissions
>   and roles.  We have it on our backlog, but have not been able to get
>   to it yet.

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  I got the same answer from MSDN.

Comment: @devlife how did you end up working around it?  I'm contemplating some scripting after generating with the DROP statements to look for anything user / role / permission-y and extracting them before having DBAs publish.

Comment: We ended up just manually deleting the statements from the generated scripts.